# Fatal exception with SDL-droid and GThread

Tags: android, opengl-es, sdl

Why am I getting this error?

```
I/System.out( 1852): libSDL: accelerometer start required: false
W/dalvikvm( 1852): No implementation found for native Lcom/starlon/froyvisuals/DemoRenderer;.nativeInit (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;I)V
W/dalvikvm( 1852): threadid=10: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40176560)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1852): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread
E/AndroidRuntime( 1852): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: nativeInit
E/AndroidRuntime( 1852):    at com.starlon.froyvisuals.DemoRenderer.nativeInit(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1852):    at com.starlon.froyvisuals.DemoRenderer.onDrawFrame(Video.java:363)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1852):    at com.starlon.froyvisuals.GLSurfaceView_SDL$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView_SDL.java:996)
W/ActivityManager(  112):   Force finishing activity com.starlon.froyvisuals/.MainActivity
I/System.out( 1852): libSDL: stopping accelerometer
V/SDL     ( 1852): GLSurfaceView_SDL::onPause()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine cannot find an appropriate native-language definition of a method declared native**

It seems some incompatibility with native library libSDL. It could be either older version (or) newer version.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the `void Java_org_libsdl_app_SDLActivity_nativeInit(JNIEnv * env, jclass cls, jobject obj)` yourself(this is your entry point). If you're using C++, take care to define its signature in an extern block like this:

```
extern "C" {
  JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_libsdl_app_SDLActivity_nativeInit(JNIEnv* env, jclass cls, jobject obj);
};
```

A skeleton of a main function can be found in https://github.com/spurious/SDL-mirror/blob/master/src/main/android/SDL_android_main.c